# Passing fetched data as props in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I changed my code to this. Now i get an error that says 'Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'query' as it is undefined.'. Does anyone know why? I destructed it but still cant reach the elements that i am passing

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';
import Update from '../update/page';

export default function Read() {
    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://64241e5a47401740433376dd.mockapi.io/crudData')
            .then((response) => {
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }, []);



    const getData = () => {
        axios.get('https://64241e5a47401740433376dd.mockapi.io/crudData')
            .then((response) => {
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }

    const onDelete = (id) => {
        axios.delete(`https://64241e5a47401740433376dd.mockapi.io/crudData/${id}`)
            .then(() => {
                getData();
            })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='table_container '>
                <table className="table bg-light rounded-3 table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className='text-muted'>
                            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Update</th>
                            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {APIData.map((data) => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{data.firstName}</td>
                                    <td>{data.lastName}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <Link href={`/update?id=${data.id}&firstName=${data.firstName}&lastName=${data.lastName}`}>
                                            <button
                                                // onClick={(data) => {
                                                //     <Update data={data}/>
                                                // }}
                                                className='btn btn-secondary'>
                                                Update
                                            </button>
                                        </Link>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => onDelete(data.id)}
                                            className='btn btn-danger'>
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <Link href="/create">
                <button
                    className='btn btn-light fw-bold'>
                    Add
                </button>
            </Link>
        </>
    )
}
```

Below is my other component that i passed the data into. But it shows it like 'undefined'

```
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Update() {
    const { push, query } = useRouter()
    const { id, firstName, lastName } = query ;
   

    const [firstName2, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName2, setLastName] = useState('');
    const updateAPIData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.put(`https://64241e5a47401740433376dd.mockapi.io/crudData/${id}`, {
            firstName2,
            lastName2,
        }).then(() => {
            push('/')
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p className="mb-5 text-light text-center pt-5 fs-3 fw-bold">Update item</p>
                <form className="mt-5" >
                    <div className="form-group text-start ">
                        <label className="text-muted mb-3">First Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="First Name"
                            value={firstName}
                            onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group text-start">
                        <label className="text-muted mb-3 mt-3">Last Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Last Name"
                            value={lastName}
                            onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group text-start">
                    </div>

                    <div className='d-flex justify-content-center mt-4'>
                        <Link href="/"><button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-secondary me-5"
                        >
                            Cancel
                        </button></Link>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-primary"
                            onClick={updateAPIData}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be destructured as so `export default function Update({data})` and then use as `{data.whatever}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### next/router

Your error `'Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'query' as it is undefined.'` is not related to props, but to `next/router`.

This is because the `router` may not be updated yet before the initial render, in which case keys like `query` would be undefined as stated in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

And if `query` is undefined, you obviously cannot do `const { id, firstName, lastName } = query;`

What you could do instead:

```js
const { id, firstName, lastName } = query || {} ;
```

In this case, if `query` is undefined, all the destructured props will also be undefined without throwing an error.

---

### Props

Also, you pass props to the `Update` component (`data={data}`) without accepting any parameters:

You need to accept data like that in order to access it inside the `Update` component:

```js
export default function Update({data})
```

Comment: I solved this another way with sending props through my URL like this.                                                             
<Link href{`/updateid=${data.id}&firstName=${data.firstName}&lastName=${data.lastName}`} >                                                                                                      And i used them in Update component like this :                                                         
  `const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  setUser({ id: params.get("id"), firstName: params.get("firstName"), lastName:params.get("lastName") })`